# Python Aiogram: Convert 'State' to 'int'

Tags: python, state, telegram, aiogram

Let's say I want:
A bot to ask how many doughnuts the user needs, and in response it receives the word "doughnuts" multiplied by the number entered by the user.

**Simple example:**

*Bot:* How many doughnuts do you want? 
*User:* 5 
*Bot:* doughnut doughnut doughnut doughnut doughnut

**Here how i see it:**

```
class how_many(StatesGroup):
   set = State()

async def doughnut(message: types.Message):
   await how_many.set.set()
   await message.reply('How many doughnuts do you want?')


async def doughnut_answer(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
   await message.reply("doughnut" * int(how_many.set))
   await State.finish()


def handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
   dp.register_message_handler(doughnut, commands='doughnuts', state=None)
   dp.register_message_handler(doughnut_answer, state=how_many.set)
```

But I am getting an error:
" int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'State' "

How do I "state" convert to "int"?
To do this, I need to save the value somewhere and then convert it? Or can I do it directly with the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does the State class look like? I assume you store the value in the State object. Furthermore, the `__int__` method must be implemented, otherwise the `int` function cannot be applied to a State object. With this method you can return the stored value (in my example below I have called this value amount):

```py
class State:

    def __int__(self):
        return self.amount
```

The `int` function only calls the `__int__` method of a class. Since your `how_many.set` is a State object, the `int` function returns the stored value amount

For more information regarding Python Magic Methods see [here](https://zetcode.com/python/magicmethods/#:%7E:text=The%20__int__%20method,%2C%20oct%20%2C%20and%20bin%20functions.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! It turns out that I need to apply this in my code in order for everything to work correctly? I just could not find a way how to do it correctly, save somewhere and then reassign or how